# How to add new local host?

Tags: linux, hostname, hosts

How can i set new local host with new hostname?

```
[main@evghost ~]$ host evghost
Host evghost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

[main@evghost ~]$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1

[main@evghost ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost

# End of file
```

i just want to have new localhost with name evghost

Comment: Like... you want "evghost" to resolve to your localhost which resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: yea, this is exactly what i want

Comment: Just a new entry in your /etc/hosts file: `127.0.0.1 evghost` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```
127.0.0.1 evghost evghost
```

You should specify your question a little more precise.

Then you try

```
localhost evghost evghost //
localhost evghost.localdomain evghost //
localhost evghost //
127.0.0.1 evghost
```

Comment: one of  them should work

Comment: they don't work both. idk why

Comment: on my pc it is working with
`127.0.0.1 hostname`

die you try to add an / after evghost when yo run it in browser? evghost/?

Comment: i just use `host localhost` and `host evghost`. First of this gives me `localhost has address 127.0.0.1` and another one `Host evghost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: You are right, its the same on my machine, but i can request this url via browser and get my default webserver page.

Comment: yeah. thanks. It helps me a lot.